# "...they were had been planning

Tags: grammar

"The gunman and Dr O'Neal had been engaged, and were had been planning to marry on 27 October - but that date passed without a wedding, according to CBS Chicago."
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-46270195

Am I correct in saying were and had shouldn't be used next to each other in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. 
As the verb of this clause, `were planning` (*past continuous* tense) and `had been planning` (*past perfect continuous* tense) are mutually exclusive.

Looks like you've found a typo !

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I have emailed them about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an editorial typo. It was originally one way, but they meant for the other version to go to print. ("*They were planning*" vs "*They had been planning*"). It might be the result of oversight or an artifact from the editing software. I expect it will be updated and corrected. (Yes, it is "wrong.")

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I have emailed them about it.

Answer (score 0):

They were planning may be changed as They had been planning in Reported speech please but not on a single sentence